# Why is my Ubuntu Installation taking more space than actual size

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, disk-space

My installation of ubuntu is taking 13.7 GB when seen from Windows Settings, but when I ran

> ncdu - -exclude /c

It shows only 4.7 GB is in use. Where is the rest of the space utilized.

[windows Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RISzB.jpg)
[ncdu output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cTCZ.jpg)

Comment: Did you account for all folders and partitions?  My guest Ubuntu 20.04 machine is 15 GB thereabouts

Comment: In other words, the *stand-alone* portion of Ubuntu, that would actually be installed on disk and is accessible in Ubuntu, is ~4 GB, the other 10 GB is take up by the work-around Windows uses to run Ubuntu.Ubuntu will run from a 4 GB flash drive! https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2-requirements